# Signature index causes test to fail

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am having trouble with my code. The typescript index signature I wrote for my code:

```
const ships: { [index: string]: Ship } = {};
```

Which is apart of this block of code:

```
recieveAttack(e: any) {
    let target: string;
    const location = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
    const ships: { [key: string]: Ship } = {};
    console.log(location.hasChildNodes());
    if (location.hasChildNodes()) {
      target = e.currentTarget.children[0].getAttribute('data-ship-type');
    }
    console.log(location.classList.contains('occupied'));
    if (location.classList.contains('occupied')) {
      console.log(target);
      console.log('hit', ships[target]);
      ships[target].hit(e.target.id);
    } else {
      this.miss(e.target.id);
    }
  }
```

is causing my tests to (written in jasmine) to pass, but for the code that was once working correctly to fail for some unknown reason. However, if i take out this line of code, the tests will fail with the error the code that puts out:

```
{
"message": "TypeError: shipContainer is null\nat spec/index_spec.ts:127:13\n\nShip.prototype.renderShip/<@spec/index_spec.ts:127:13\nShip.prototype.renderShip@spec/index_spec.ts:118:9\n@spec/index_spec.ts:463:5\n@spec/index_spec.ts:457:2\n__webpack_require__@spec/index_spec.ts:20:12\n@spec/index_spec.ts:374:68\n__webpack_require__@spec/index_spec.ts:20:12\n@spec/index_spec.ts:69:18\n@spec/index_spec.ts:1:11\n",
"str": "TypeError: shipContainer is null\nat spec/index_spec.ts:127:13\n\nShip.prototype.renderShip/<@spec/index_spec.ts:127:13\nShip.prototype.renderShip@spec/index_spec.ts:118:9\n@spec/index_spec.ts:463:5\n@spec/index_spec.ts:457:2\n__webpack_require__@spec/index_spec.ts:20:12\n@spec/index_spec.ts:374:68\n__webpack_require__@spec/index_spec.ts:20:12\n@spec/index_spec.ts:69:18\n@spec/index_spec.ts:1:11\n"
```

}

The block of code the error is point to is:

```
renderShip(): HTMLElement {
    const ship: any[] = this.createShip();
    const shipContainer: HTMLElement = document.querySelector(`#${ this.type() }`);

    ship.forEach((value: string, index: number) => {
      const section: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div');

      section.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
      section.setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'false');
      section.setAttribute('data-direction', 'horizontal');
      section.setAttribute('data-ship-type', this.type());

      section.classList.add('ship');
      section.classList.add(this.type());
      section.id = this.type() + String(index);
      shipContainer.appendChild(section);
    });

    shipContainer.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const ship = shipContainer.children;

      for (let i = 0; i < ship.length; i = i + 1) {
        ship[i].setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'true');
      }
    });

    shipContainer.setAttribute('data-direction', 'horizontal');

    shipContainer.addEventListener('dragstart', (e: any) => {
      drag(e);
    });

    return shipContainer;
  }
```

specifically this line:

```
const shipContainer: HTMLElement = document.querySelector(`#${ this.type() }`);
```

I should specify that i am using jasmine-jquery for fixtures. The code code shipContainer should point to 1 of serveral ship dynamically added to the dom depending on the length of the ship.

Ships module

```
import { Ship } from './ship';

export module Ships {
  export const patrol: Ship = new Ship(2);
  export const destroyer: Ship = new Ship(3);
  export const submarine: Ship = new Ship(3);
  export const battleship: Ship = new Ship(4);
  export const carrier: Ship = new Ship(5);

  carrier.renderShip();
  battleship.renderShip();
  submarine.renderShip();
  destroyer.renderShip();
  patrol.renderShip();
}
```

I have no clue why one simple line of code is causing my code to clash with my test. If the signature index is there everything works fine, but then i can't call the hit method of ships[target]. And, if it isn't there i running into my tests failing. Any insight or fixes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those are runtime errors. They cannot be the result of type annotations.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time amount of searching. I found the answer to my problems.

The solution:

```
recieveAttack(e: any) {
    const location = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
    type ships = { [key: string]: Ship };
    const ships2: ships = { ...ships };
    let target: string;

    if (location.hasChildNodes()) {
      target = e.currentTarget.children[0].getAttribute('data-ship-type');
    }

    if (location.classList.contains('occupied')) {
      ships2[target].hit(e.target.id);
    } else {
      this.miss(e.target.id);
    }
  }
```